# How to determine most often element in postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

If we have a column similar to this:

```
2012
2013
2012
2012
2011
```

How to determine which year is more used than the others? (in this example it would be 2012, since there are 3 entries with this year).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to calculate numbers of occurences for all elements
order them by this number in descending order, and take the first one:

```
SELECT element
FROM table1
GROUP BY element
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
;
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/47e59/2

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
select my_col_date, rank() over (order by used_count desc) 
from
(
SELECT my_col_date, count(my_col_date) used_count
  FROM my_table
  group by 1
) A
limit 1
```

OR

```
SELECT my_col_date, count(my_col_date) used_count
  FROM my_table
  group by 1
  order by count(my_col_date) limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use R:

```
# get your data into R first
table(as.numeric(dataFromDb$column))
```